# Using a UIScrollView to change the alpha of an image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, alpha, uiscrollviewdelegate

My aim is to effectively use a UIScrollView as a UISlider.

I've managed to code a UISlider to change the alpha of an image however I want to code a scrollview to change the alpha of an image when it is scrolled.

I think I'm on the right lines by using the scroll views content offset to adjust alpha balances in the scroll view delegate but I just can't seem to get the code to work!

Any suggestions on how I can get do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show some code, what you have tried, and where your code seems to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have right... use the scroll view offset to modify the alpha:

For example:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { 

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 150.0) {
        float percent = (scrollView.contentOffset.y / 150.0);
               self.imageView.alpha = percent;

    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 150.0){
        self.imageView.alpha = 1;

    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
       // do other ... ;
    }
}
```

here you have an example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/ScrollView_alpha.zip

So... happy coding!

Comment: you can accept the answer, too … if it’s ok for you :))

Comment: the example project was perfect along with the code, thanks for your help!